# How to apply functions stored in a column to other values in the row SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a table with function names 'testTable' and would like to use the functions stored in the 'Function' column on values 'Value 1' and 'Value 2'. The 'Function' stores the names of functions which I already have in my schema.

I have this code, but obviously it does not like the `dbo.[Function]` I have tried using the function as a variable and without the 'dbo' but still, doesn't work.

```
SELECT *, 
CASE 
    WHEN [Function] IS NOT NULL 
        THEN dbo.[Function]([Value 1],[Value 2])
    ELSE NULL END AS Result
FROM testTable t
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to dynamically generate the sql statement as data and the code are separated from each other.

Comment: This, honestly, sounds like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: How many different functions do you have, are they defined up front? And why are you using functions anyway? A [mcve] would help